# Let $X$ be a totally ordered set and $\forall U\subseteq X$ s.t. $U\neq\emptyset$ has both a max. and min., then $X$ is finite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, order-theory

Proof:
Let $X$ be a totally ordered set and $\forall U\subseteq X$ s.t. $U\neq\emptyset$ has both a minimum and a maximum. We want to show that X is finite. For the sake of contradiction, suppose  $X$ is infinite. We should show $\exists U\subseteq X$ where $U $does not have both a minimum and a maximum. Which, equivalently, mean that $\forall U\subseteq X$ such that $U$ has both a max. and a min. is false. Now we define $X_0:=\{\alpha\in X:x_0\leq\alpha\leq x_n\}$ where $x_0$ is the minimum and $x_n$ is the maximum. In case that, $\forall x\in X, x\in X_0$ then $X\subseteq X_0$ and $X=X_0$. So we consider $X^*\subseteq X_0$ such that $X^*:=\{\alpha_j\in X_0:x_0\leq\alpha_j< x_n \}=X_0\setminus \{x_n\}$. Since $\forall \alpha_k\in X^*, \alpha_k\leq x_n$ and $X^*\subset X$ then $X^*$ is the subset of $X$ not containing both a maximum and a minimum which yields a contradiction.

Comment: "For the sake of contradiction, suppose $X$ is infinite then $\exists U\subseteq X$ where does not have both a minimum and a maximum". If I assume that, what is there left to prove?

Comment: what do you mean? how so? help..

Comment: If you assume that the counternominal of the theorem is true, then you are already assuming that the theorem is true, and all subsequent reasonings are just tautologies.

Comment: I think I made an error copying my proof

Comment: I just added the corrections now.

Comment: How do you know $X^*$ does not contain a maximum? $X$ could have a second largest element which is now the maximum of $X^*$.

Comment: You are right. Let me think a bit more.

Comment: @FlorianR, what if I define $X^*:=\{\alpha_j\in X:x_0\leq\alpha_j<x_n\}$? So that it includes all possible elements in $X$ that are less than $x_n$. I'm trying to use $\Bbb{R}$ as an analogy.

Comment: I need some clarifaction: what are $x_0$ and $x_n$ the minimum/maximum of? It sounded as if they are the minimum/maximum of $X$, but then $X_0 = X$ and your new $X^*$ is the same as your old $X^*$.

Comment: $X_0=X$ is only for the case when $X$ is contained in $X_0$, but is not necessarily always the case. What I was trying to say there is "if all of $X$ can be found between the minimum and maximum of $X_0$ then $X=X_0$" thanks!

Comment: You can actually assume that $X_0 = X$ because otherwise you already found your contradiction with $U=X$, i.e. you can take $x_0$ and $x_n$ to be the minimum/maximum of $X$. (Though, the notation $x_n$ then is misleading since $|X| = \infty$). On the other hand, I am not yet sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: So you mean I can assume $X$ to have $x_0$ and $x_n$ as minimum and maximum, respectively? Though, I don't understand what you meant by I've already found my contradiction with $U=X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is doomed to fail. There are infinite linear orders where every non-empty subset has a minimum. It's just that not every subset has a maximum. This is the case with $\Bbb N$ with the usual order. And there are other linear orders with the converse property.

The point is that the negation of "Every non-empty subset has a minimum and maximum" is "There is a non-empty subset without a minimum *or* without a maximum".

So your goal needs to be to assume that $X$ is an infinite linear order where every set has a minimum, and find a subset which does not have a maximum. Or assume that every subset has a maximum, and find a subset without a minimum element.

---

But in any case, a direct proof is also possible. Let $U$ be the set of points that have infinitely many points below them in $X$. If $U$ is non-empty, it has a minimum, $x$ and you can show that $\{y\in X\mid y<x\}$ has no maximum, since every $y$ in that set has finitely many predecessors, but $x$ has infinitely many of them. So $U$ has to be empty. Apply a similar argument to tail segments to show that there is no point in $X$ that has infinitely many points above it.

Now pick any point $x$, since $X$ is a union of those points below $x$, those points above $x$, and $\{x\}$, and all three sets are finite, $X$ is finite.

Comment: So $T=\{y\in X\vert y<x\}$ has no maximum because $x\notin T$? If that's the case then I think I am trying to show a similar thing with my set $X^*:=\{\alpha\in X_0:x_0\leq\alpha_j<x_n\}=X_0\setminus \{x_n\}$ or is that technically different?

Comment: No, that $x$ is not in $T$ is not enough to conclude there is no maximum to $T$. You need to use the assumption we have about $x$, being the least member that has infinitely many points below it.

Comment: Well first thank you for being patient. Here is what I think I understand from your proof. "There are infinite linear orders where every non-empty subset has a minimum. It's just that not every subset has a maximum."$\Rightarrow$"If $U$ is non-empty then it has a minimum $x$". Then this is where I don't quite understand "$U$ have infinitely many points below and $x$ is not in $T$" $\Rightarrow$ $T=\{y\in X\vert y<x\}$ has no maximum.

Comment: I tried to clarify this a bit more.

Comment: the goal clarification helped. thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Assume X is infinite and let $x_1$ be the bottom element of X.
Let $X_1$ = X - {$x_1$} and $x_2$ the bottom element of $X_1$.
Continue in this manner creating the set { $x_j$ : j in N }.
which has no maximum.

Comment: Would you "Continue in this manner" be formal enough or I have to fill in?

Comment: Formalize it to your school master's content @TheLastCipher.